# SharePoint server 2013 REST API permissions (sites, list, folder, item)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Prompt there is an opportunity by means of REST API of the right to give out to users and groups of users on a site, the list, a folder, an element of the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for setting up custom permissions to a SPUser/SPGroup for a site/list/Folder/list item. 
I am explaining here one sample use of REST API for setting up custom permission to a list. You can Follow similar approaches for other part of your need.

Action Plan:

1. Break Role inheritance for SP List
2. Set custom permission level (Full control, Edit etc.)
   for 2nd point you need to do a little extra work to get 2 parameters: 
   PrincipalId (ID of User/Group) and RoleDefId (ID of Permission level). you can use below api go get these:

Your_Site_url/_api/web /siteusers - get user ID

Your_Site_url/_api/web /sitegroups - get group ID

Your_Site_url/_api/web/roledefinitions - get Perm level ID

*Note: Make sure you are already logged into you sharepoint environment before hitting these URLs on your browser. And also the logged in User should have sufficient permissions (eg. Site admin/Owner)*

Now use the below script:

```
var headers = {  
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
    "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()  
}   
var endPointUrl = "your_site_url/" + "_api/web/lists/getByTitle('xxxxx')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true, clearSubscopes=true)";            
var call = $.ajax(  
    {  
        url: endPointUrl,  
        type: "POST",  
        headers: headers,  
        dataType: 'json',  
        success: function (data)  
        {                      
                    //Add Role Permissions   
                    var endPointUrlRoleAssignment = "your_site_url/" + "_api/web/lists/getByTitle('xxxx')/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=xx,roleDefId=xxxxxx)";  
                    var call = $.ajax(  
                    {  
                        url: endPointUrlRoleAssignment,  
                        type: "POST",  
                        headers: headers,  
                        dataType: 'json',  
                        success: function (data)  
                        {  
                            alert('Permission Granted successfully !');  
                        },  
                        error: function (error)  
                        {  
                            alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
                        }  
                    });  
                },  
                error: function (error)  
                {  
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
                }  
        });  
});
```